# Using certain OpenGL functions with Qt 5.4 on Linux…

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

The following code block below works on Windows (in VC++ 2013) because I have included GL/glew.h but using QT Creator on Linux it undefines the include so the functions in bold below are not available.

What can I do to be able to use the OpenGL functions **glGetUniformBlockIndex()**, **glUniformBlockBinding()**, and **glBindBufferBase()** under Linux like how I use these functions under Windows?

Thank you for your time.

```
void QTOpenGLWindow::loadShaderUniforms() {

 glUseProgram(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID);

 MatricesUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "Matrices");
 glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, MatricesUniformBlockID, 1);
 glGenBuffers(1, &MatricesUniformBufferID);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MatricesUniformBufferID);
 glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, MatricesUniformBufferID);
 GLsizeiptr TotalBufferSize = sizeof(glm::mat4) + sizeof(glm::mat4);
 TotalBufferSize += sizeof(glm::mat3);

 glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

 LightsUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "Lights");
 glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, LightsUniformBlockID, 2);
 glGenBuffers(1, &LightsUniformBufferID);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, LightsUniformBufferID);
 glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2, LightsUniformBufferID);

 GLfloat LightDirection[3] = { -4.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f };

 glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(LightDirection), &LightDirection, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

 MaterialsUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "Materials");
 glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, MaterialsUniformBlockID, 3);
 glGenBuffers(1, &MaterialsUniformBufferID);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MaterialsUniformBufferID);
 glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 3, MaterialsUniformBufferID);

 GLfloat Material[18];

 //Diffuse
 Material[0] = 0.5f;
 Material[1] = 0.0f;
 Material[2] = 0.0f;
 Material[3] = 1.0f;

 //Ambient
 Material[4] = 0.2f;
 Material[5] = 0.2f;
 Material[6] = 0.2f;
 Material[7] = 1.0f;

 //Specular
 Material[8] = 1.0f;
 Material[9] = 1.0f;
 Material[10] = 1.0f;
 Material[11] = 1.0f;

 //Emissive
 Material[12] = 0.0f;
 Material[13] = 0.0f;
 Material[14] = 0.0f;
 Material[15] = 1.0f;

 //Shininess
 Material[16] = 5.0f;

 //Texture Count
 Material[17] = 0.0f;

 glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(Material), &Material, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

}
```

Comment: Why they're not available? Where/how are you using GLEW in that code? (Also, Qt already provides something similar to GLEW. Take a look at the `qopengl.h' header (which will include the right `gl.h` header), as well as `QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions` (which returns a class with the function pointers already resolved for a given version/profile))

Answer (score 0):

You could try that:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#endif
```

That's what we do on the project I work on right now. I wasn't the one to set that up but I think it's worth giving it a shot.
If you're interested in checking out the original code, it's over here on [Github](https://github.com/highfidelity/hifi/blob/master/libraries/gpu/src/gpu/GPUConfig.h).